# How to get access to an iPod Touch 3rd gen wich currently is in recovery mode?

Tags: ipod

I have an old iPod stuck in recovery mode. I know it's old, but I can't afford anything new. Is there any way to get it out of recovery mode without losing my music?

PS: I don't have the original computer I used to use. Some of the music is in the cloud, but half of them are not.

Answer (score 2):

There are many tools that might help. However, the following tool was recommended by my colleague, so I thought to share it. I haven't tested or owned any rights for this tool.

You need one third party tool and a reference computer to resolve this issue.

1) Link to Download Recboot > [RecBoot for Mac](https://www.cydiaos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/RecBoot-2.2-Mac.zip) and [RecBoot for Windows](https://www.cydiaos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/RecBoot-1.3-WIN.zip)

2) Run Recboot, then connect your iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch to your computer.

3) Once your iOS device is recognized, you’ll find two buttons on the Recboot window.

[image]

4) The Button on the left is to “Enter Recovery Mode” and the right one is to “Exit Recovery Mode”.

5) After you make sure your device is connected properly, click the desired button to enter a command to your iPhone from your computer.

Note: I don't own or advertising this tool. You can use it at your own risk.